# Programmatically binding List to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let's say, for instance, I have the following extremely simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="CalendarGenerator.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="300"
        Width="447">
  <Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="12,40,0,12"
             Name="eventList"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Width="134" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And a simple list defined as:

```
List<String> ListOfNames = new List<String>();
```

And let's assume that the list has several names in it. How would I go about binding the List to the ListBox using as much code-behind as possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First you'd need to give your ListBox a name so that it's accessible from your code behind (*edit* I note you've already done this, so I'll change my example ListBox's name to reflect yours):

```
<ListBox x:Name="eventList" ... />
```

Then it's as simple as setting the ListBox's [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to your list:

```
eventList.ItemsSource = ListOfNames;
```

Since you've defined your "ListOfNames" object as a `List<String>`, the ListBox won't automatically reflect changes made to the list. To get WPF's databinding to react to changes within the list, define it as an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)`<String>` instead.

Answer (score 20):

If the data list is created in code then you're going to have to bind it in code, like so:

```
eventList.ItemsSource = ListOfNames;
```

Now binding to a list of strings is a very simple example. Let's take a more complex one.

Say you have a person class:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

To display a list of persons you could bind a list to the ListBox, but you'll end up with a listbox that displays "Person" for each entry, because you haven't told WPF how to display a person object.

To tell WPF how to visually display data objects we define a DataTemplate like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Person}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listBox" />
</Grid>

public Window1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Cameron", Surname = "MacFarland" });
    people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bea", Surname = "Stollnitz" });
    people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jason", Surname = "Miesionczek" });
    listBox.ItemsSource = people;
}
```

This will nicely display "Firstname Surname" in the list.

If you wanted to change the look to be say "**Surname**, Firstname" all you need to do is change the XAML to:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
    <TextBlock Text=", "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) class if you want to customize binding:

```
List<String> listOfNames = new List<String>() {"a", "b"};
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
//set binding parameters if necessary
myBinding.Source = listOfNames;
eventList.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

or

directly assign data to ItemsSource property:

```
eventList.ItemsSource = listOfNames;
```

Answer (score 2):

eventList.ItemsSource = ListOfNames;