# Bind ListBoxItems using Code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I try to bind XAML `ListBoxItem` using Code but doesn't seem work

In my XAML:

> ```
> <Window.Resources>
>     <local:FooList x:Key="FooListItem" />
> </Window.Resources>
> ```
>
> < ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FooListItem}}" />

In my code:

> ```
> public class FooList
> {
>     add some items; // I tried variation of that but didn't get it to work
> }
> ```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create `ListBoxItem` from code.

You just provide a `ListBox` with collection of your CLR class objects, provide an `ItemTemplate` and it implicitly wraps an `ItemTemplate` inside a `ListBoxItem`.

Example:

```
public class FooList
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> Items { get; set; }

    public FooList()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Source={StaticResource FooListItem}}" />
```

Comment: I can do it in XAML. But I cannot do this in code? How could you provide ItemTemplate in code?

Comment: Thanks for more detail. But I need to do that without observableCollection.  I am following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#without_a_datatemplate and they were able to bind ItemsSource but didn't provide any explanation...

Comment: That is because `Tasks` type in that example is a `Collection` itself.

Comment: I guess I'm not making my question clear, please see this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451171

Answer (score 1):

[Programmatically binding List to ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449410/programmatically-binding-list-to-listbox)

[Listbox with custom drawn data bound objects](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/145733-listbox-with-custom-drawn-data-bound-objects/)

[Data Binding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)

[Windows Presentation Foundation Data Binding: Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx)

Comment: I'm actually following a tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#without_a_datatemplate but it doesn't show any C# code and I can't figure it out.
Your tutorial link also doesn't show any code.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449410/programmatically-binding-list-to-listbox