# msdn Data Templating Overview

Tags: c#, wpf, staticresource

I'm following msdn data templating overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

But I felt they missed explaining something..for resources they have:

```
 <Window.Resources><local:Tasks x:Key="myTodoList"/></Window.Resources>
```

And all they have in XAML is

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}"/>
```

Without showing how C# code behind, they were able to show a list of items in the ListBox. The ListBox has no x:Name and I can't add the items in MainWindow, and with a separate class Tasks, I did the following (which doesn't work)

```
using System.Collections; // use ArrayList
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; // use Observable Collection

namespace FooApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Tasks>
    {
        string TaskName;
        string Description;
        int Priority;

        public TasksStuff(string taskName, string description, int priority)
        {
            this.taskName = TaskName;
            this.description = Description;
            this.priority = Priority;
        }

        public string TaskName
        {get{return this.taskName}}

        public string Description
        {get{return this.description}}

        public string Priority
        {get{return this.priority}}

        private ArrayList Tasks
        {
            ArrayList taskList = new ArrayList();
            taskList.Add( new TasksStuff("A foo task", "doing foo",1));
            return taskList;
        }
    }
}
```

I am really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the definition of `Tasks` for your sample to work correctly:

```
public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Task /*or whatever type you want to use here*/>
{
    //...
}
```

--EDIT--

```
// This is a class to store information for a single task
// It has nothing to do with a collection of tasks
public class Task
{
    private String _taskName;
    public String TaskName
    {
        get { return _taskName; }
        set { _taskName = value; }
    }

    private String _description;
    public String Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }

    private Int32 _priority;
    public Int32 Priority
    {
        get { return _priority; }
        set { _priority = value; }
    }

    public Task(String taskName, String description, Int32 priority)
    {
        this.TaskName = taskName;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Priority = priority;
    }
}

// This is a class that is a collection of Task types
// Since it inherits from ObservableCollection, it is itself a collection
// There is no need to declare/create an ArrayList inside.
// And on a strict note, do not ever use ArrayList. It is obsolete and not strongly typed.
// Use List<T>, ObservableCollection<T>, etc. instead.
// Look for more Generic Collections in System.Collections.Generic namespace
public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Task>
{
    public Tasks()
    {
        Add(new Task("A foo task", "doing foo", 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot datalist.Add to the ArrayList class. How shall I add to the array?

Comment: I have edited my question with the full code. I get errors here and there and just can't figure out how it works for 14 hours straight...I'm trying to look for tutorial but this is where in the tutorial I'm getting stuck at with no solution...