# Programmatically bind an ObservableCollection to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This question looks like this one :
[Programmatically binding List to ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449410/programmatically-binding-list-to-listbox)
but as far as my example is concerned, the answers given in this post doesn't work for me !
Anyway, I looked at about 10/15 similar posts but none worked

Here is my xaml code :

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxx"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            Random random = new Random();
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MyCollection.Add(random.Next(0, 100).ToString());
            };
            aTimer.Interval = 500;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Binding myBinding2 = new Binding();
            myBinding2.Source = this;
            myBinding2.Path = new PropertyPath("MyCollection");
            ListBoxx.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, my class doesn't have to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged cause I use an ObservableCollection.

I don't wanna use a {Binding} in xaml code.

I tried this code :

```
ListBoxx.ItemsSource = MyCollection;
```

this "works" but I got a thread crash. I know I can use Dispatcher to fix it but it doesn't fix with my code. I wanna use a "real" binding (configurable) like in my code snippet.

The result is that I got no error but the ListBox just doesn't update :/

I tried to add the lines :

```
MyCollection.Add("aaa");
MyCollection.Add("bbb");
MyCollection.Add("ccc");
MyCollection.Add("ddd");
```

but I don't get anything in my application so I really think this is a binding problem. Anyway, I'm SURE that my Timer is OK, The problem's not here.

I tried too to get MyCollection as Property like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get { return _MyCollection; } }
```

but it doesn't work too :/ (no error but no update)

Comment: A WPF UI element gets its data from Dispatcher.  Trying to use path versus ItemsSource is not going to fool it.  Why are you opposed to binding in XAML?  In the end it resolves to the same binding.  In code does provide more debugging.   You timer may be behaving but between the timer and the UI is Dispatcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted is going to fail because "MyCollection" isn't a property in MainWindow. Your Visual Studio output window is probably showing binding errors.

Additionally you indeed need to dispatch the changes you make to the collection, you can use a DispatcherTimer to do this. There should be errors in the output window about that too.

The code below works:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Random random = new Random();
        DispatcherTimer aTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        aTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MyCollection.Add(random.Next(0, 100).ToString());
        };
        aTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,500);
        aTimer.Start();

        Binding myBinding2 = new Binding();
        myBinding2.Source = this;
        myBinding2.Path = new PropertyPath("MyCollection");
        ListBoxx.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding2);
    }
}
```

Comment: wooow, this code is like a gift from god for me ! The way you define the Timer is what I was looking for for days... It changes everything for a lot of troubles I had, woow, so bad I can't give you more +1 :(

Comment: I gave you an extra From Guillaume since he was so happy :) and it kinda helped me out as well

Answer (score 2):

The first case cannot work as bindings only work on properties. If you create a property as shown at the end it should work, given of course that the bound object's `DataContext` or the `Binding.Source` is the object containing the property.

Do you get *binding errors*? Have you tried to [debug it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: Im not sure what u mean by "errors" but everything seems fine. No error, no crash but just an empty listbow with no update

Comment: yep, im reading and trying it ! I was clarifying about the "error" question