# C# WPF DataTemplate binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I bind `MyListBox` to a List of MyObject instances. MyObject contains a string field named TextField. I want to bind every item in listBox to `MyObject.TextField`. My code is the following, but it doesn't work.

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextField}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What is the proper way to do that?

**Solved: TextField of My Object's class wasn't a property**

Comment: Either post a proper answer and accept it or delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set the ListBox's [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding theList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextField}" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: In this way it even doesn't bind to theList.

Comment: @HelloWorld Do you have the DataContext of the Window/UserControl set properly?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you mean

Comment: @HelloWorld The DataContext of an object tells it where to look for bindings.  You must set it on your Window or UserControl or all bindings will fail.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to set DataContext for the Window?

Comment: @HelloWorld Is "theList" part of the window?  If so, in the window's constructor, after InitializeComponent, add: `this.DataContext = this;`  If its a different class, you can set it to the class instance.

Comment: Also I can bind to theList only in code but ItemsSource="{Binding theList}" doesn't bind it

Comment: @HelloWorld: Is "theList" a **public property** of your class?  Binding only works against properties (not fields)...

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: i tried the solution in VS 2010...here is the code

first you create your own class, for example person class

```
class Person
{

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

then you create listbox in xaml like this

```
<ListBox Height="222" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,28,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

note in xaml Path=Name is the property which you want to display in the listbox

in the code behind file, enter the following code

```
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person("person 1"));
        persons.Add(new Person("person 2"));
```

Comment: in the behind code file after initializecomponent method, set the itemsource property of your listbox to the list of MyObjects. for example  MyListBox.ItemSource = listMyObjects

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449410/programmatically-binding-list-to-listbox